# How to override a protocol's default method behavior of a 3rd party library?

Tags: swift, overriding, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

```
// MARK: - Third Party Library

public protocol TestProtocol: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(str: String)
}

extension TestProtocol {
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(str: value)
    }
}

public struct Test {
    public let str: String
    
    public init(str: String) {
        self.str = str
    }
}

extension Test: TestProtocol {}

// MARK: - My Swift Package

extension Test {
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(str: "Roman")
    }
}

let test: Test = "Test"
print(test.str)
```

This is playground-friendly code snippet and it works as expected. I'm overriding the initializer so that the code always prints "Roman" no matter what we're really assigning.

But as soon as I move "Third Party Library" code into playground's "Sources" folder (to imitate the usage of third party library) the behavior changes: my overrided method is just ignored

[image]

Comment: Please show what the problematic code looks life. Note that there is no "override" here; it's a matter of how things are typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The two modules are compiled separately, and when

```
extension Test: TestProtocol {}
```

is compiled, the compiler needs to generate the protocol witness table of `Test` for the conformance of `TestProtocol`. This table basically stores which thing in `Test` implements which requirement in `TestProtocol`. Callers that don't know the concrete type of something of type `TestProtocol` would use this table to find the actual implementation they should call, e.g.

```
func f<T: TestProtocol>(_ string: TestProtocol.StringLiteralType) -> T {
    // compiler would generate code here that looks up the protocol witness table of T
    // and finds the correct implementation of init to call
    T.init(stringLiteral: string)
}
```

Although the compiler could just transform `let test: Test = "Test"` to `let test: Test = Test(stringLiteral: "Test")` (which would have called the `init` in the `Test` extension), it is instead implemented to call the protocol witness of `ExpressibleByStringLiteral.init(stringLiteral:)`.

When generating the protocol witness table, the compiler obviously will not see the one you declared in `extension Test`, because the files are compiled separately.

Of course, if the compiler had seen the one declared in `extension Test`, it would have chosen that one instead of the default implementation.

So nothing outside the library can change what `let test: Test = "Test"` does.

Comment: Just want to notice, that I managed to successfully "override" static func buildFinalResult of a resultBuilder from the same library. It confused me so I posted the question. Apparently static functions and protocol methods work differently. So we can "override" static functions but cannot "override" protocol methods.

Comment: One more interesting detail which surprised me is that the declaration "extension Test: TestProtocol {}" doesn't have "public" modifier, but we can see the effect "from the outside" anyways.